# Why additional argument allows calling from a template some function declared later?

Tags: c++, templates, argument-dependent-lookup

I would like to write a template that calls some function declared later in the code. The simplest approach does not work, unfortunately:

```
template<class T>
void g(T t) { f(t); }

template<class T>
void f(T) {}
```

because of the error:

```
call to function 'f' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
```

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/8Mh9rYzvW

But if I add an additional unused argument to the calling function that does not depend on the template parameter:

```
struct A{};

template<class T>
void g(T t) { f(A{}, t); }

template<class T>
void f(A, T) {}
```

it starts working magically, online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/YqqWvWosM

Could you please explain how this additional argument helps here? Is it because of argument-dependent lookup that is performed additionally for `A`?

Comment: "_Is it because of argument-dependent lookup that is performed additionally for A?_": Yes. That's basically the whole answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup  is pretty much that. One should be careful, because some compilers do not respect ADL rule for a call of non-template functions and allow such function to be part of global namespace while arguments are part of some namespace.